# Return Base 9 equivalent formula

Tags: language-agnostic

I have been tackling an exercise given to us by our instructor which is to return the "**base 9**" equivalent of an inputted number.

The input number is: **231085** and the
return number is: **382871**.

I have no idea how he came up with that so called "base 9" equivalent.
I tried looking for the formula on how to get the base 9 equivalent in the web but they were to difficult for me to understand, plus the fact that I am very weak in Math and Algebra.

I tried using modulo and division to solve it and came up with nothing (of course, my formula was wrong).

I'm really dumbfounded on this problem and I would appreciate it if anyone can enlighten me on the formula to solve it.

Or maybe the answer or the problem itself is all wrong?

Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

The base-9 numbering system is a system that uses nine digits to represent numbers. That is,

231,085 =    2 × 10<sup>5</sup>
                 + 3 × 10<sup>4</sup>
                 + 1 × 10<sup>3</sup>
                 + 0 × 10<sup>2</sup>
                 + 8 × 10<sup>1</sup>
                 + 5 × 10<sup>0</sup>

in the base-10 system, a.k.a. the decimal numbering system. But in the base-9 system, you write it terms of whole multiples of powers of 9, instead of powers of 10 as shown above:

381,881 =    3 × 9<sup>5</sup>
                 + 8 × 9<sup>4</sup>
                 + 1 × 9<sup>3</sup>   (Your instructor gave you the wrong number, btw. It's 381,881 not 382,871)
                 + 8 × 9<sup>2</sup>
                 + 8 × 9<sup>1</sup>
                 + 1 × 9<sup>0</sup>

Note that the coefficients of the powers of 10 in the base-10 representation (i.e., the 2, 3, 1, 0, 8, and 5) are always one of the ten decimal digits (zero through nine). Likewise, the coefficients of the powers of 9 in the base-9 representation (the 3, 8, 1, 8, 8, 1) are always one of the nine decimal digits (zero through eight). Anything more and you'd have to carry it over, like you learned in the addition of multi-digit numbers in elementary school.

Now, for the algorithm to convert the base-10 representation to base-9, first take a look at [Converting a decimal number into binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591241/converting-a-decimal-number-into-binary) which converts from base-10 to base-2. The only difference is that you'd divide by powers of 9, instead of powers of 2 as this question does.

Following the example in the linked question,

```
            [231085]  [53938]   [1450]   [721]   [73]   [1]  
             ÷59049    ÷6561     ÷729     ÷81     ÷9    ÷1
              [3]       [8]       [1]     [8]     [8]   [1]
```

If you want to systematically break down a base-10 integer into its digits, you'd follow this pattern:

1. Divide the number by 10 (the base).
2. The remainder of the division will be the next least significant digit.
3. Repeat with the new divided number (i.e. the quotient of the division of step 1) until the quotient reaches 0.

So, for 231,085, the iterations are as follows:

```
 Step:         1          2        3       4      5       6
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Number:    231,085    23,108    2,310    231     23      2
                ÷10       ÷10      ÷10    ÷10    ÷10    ÷10
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Quotient:   23,108     2,310      231     23     2       0  <-- Quotient reached 0, so stop
 Remainder:       5         8        0      1     3       2
```

As you can see, the remainder in each step is the next least significant digit in the number 231,085. That means 5 is the least significant digit. Then comes 8, which is really 8 × 10 = 80, and 10 > 1; then 0 × 100, and 100 > 10, etc.

Now if you were to divide by 9 in each step instead of by 10 as above, then the table would look something like

```
 Step:         1          2        3       4       5      6
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Number:    231,085    25,676    2,852    316     35      3
                 ÷9        ÷9       ÷9     ÷9     ÷9     ÷9
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Quotient:   25,676     2,852      316     35      3      0
 Remainder:       1         8        8      1      8      3
```

And now the remainders are in reverse order of the base-9 representation of the base-10 number 231,085.

This answer doesn't actually give you the code for the base conversion, but the basic logic is outlined above, and the algorithm exists all over the internet (maybe for different bases, but all you need to change is the base in the division).

Answer (score 1):

Your instructor's answer is incorrect.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=231085+in+base+9

Comment: This is true, but please try to provide a bit of explanation as to why it is incorrect if that is so. :)